# Why do I get AH00526 Syntax Error and Invalid "command '\xc2\xa0'" when I restart apache2?

Tags: apache, syntax-error, apache2, passenger, virtualhost

I am following this Apache-Passenger [integration guide](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/apache/deploy/ruby/) for hosting Ruby Apps. I have come across what appears to be an encoding error.

I created a test.conf file at the location `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and added the following virtual host entry to the file:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName some.domain.net
        ServerAlias some.domain.net

    # Tell Apache and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
    DocumentRoot /var/www/myApp/code/public

    PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby2.3

    # Relax Apache security settings
    <Directory /var/www/myApp/code/public>
      Allow from all
      Options -MultiViews
      # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
      Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I then enabled the test.conf file by running `a2ensite test.conf`. However, when I tried to restart the apache server using `sudo apache2ctl restart`, I get this error output:

```
Nov 11 13:57:11 myserver apachectl[25287]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/test.conf:
Nov 11 13:57:11 myserver apachectl[25287]: Invalid command '\xc2\xa0', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not include
```

Full screenshot here:
[Error message: Apache failed to restart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsIpR.png)

The first error refers to line 2 of my test.conf file, which is the `ServerName` field in the format of some.domain.net (leads to my DDNS provider). I don't see how this could be causing the error?
The second error points to an invalid command which translates to 'Non-breaking space' in UTF-8, what is this all about?

Any pointers on how to fix this would be amazing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like you have some invisible whitespace characters in that file at the mentioned location. I suggest you delete those lines, save the file, reopen it and retype the lines.

Comment: Thanks @arkascha, that was exactly my issue. Apparantly it doesn't like the line indentation. A hexdump revealed quite a lot of whitespace characters.